# Return a String WITHOUT the first two characters with exceptions like if the first character is 'a' then return it

Tags: java, string

I am a little stuck here. I have no clue what to do for the next step..Please anyone help...The solution should break a string like FrontTwo("Hello") → "llo"
FrontTwo("java") → "va"
FrontTwo("away") → "aay"

```
public String FrontTwo(String str) {    






 private String Manipulate(String str) {

 String count = '';
 for (int i = 0;i<str.length();i++){
   if (str.charAt(0) == 'a'){ 
   count+=i;

  }
   if (str.charAt(1) == 'b'){ 
   count+=i; 

 }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a variable and save any exceptions to the rule like your `a` and `b` exceptions. Then just combine the variable with the rest of the string.  Something like this:

```
private static String FrontTwo(String str){
    String beginning = "";

    if (str.charAt(0) == 'a'){
        beginning += 'a';
    }
    if (str.charAt(1) == 'b'){
        beginning += 'b';
    }
    //go through any more exceptions

    //Concat beginning to the end
    return beginning + str.substring(2);
```

Output for your cases:

```
llo
va
aay
```

Comment: Thanks gonzo! Your technique was a jem ;)

Comment: There is one more question i have regarding strings. If you see this line here    x.substring(x.length() - 1).equals("1")     ..What i want to do is have a range of numbers to check from, like .contains ("1" || "3" || "4")  instead of just having one..Hope you understood the question..If you did then how should i do it? Thanks

Comment: @user1792859 but you want to keep the whole string if it matches one of the numbers or you just want to keep the numbers that match?

Comment: i want to keep the whole string if it matches one of the numbers :)

Comment: @user1792859 did you figure this out?

Comment: Hey Yes i did! :) But thanks for your time and help..There might be more questions coming up for you in the future

Comment: how should i set a condition when I am setting a check for a value in string? Now I have it like this      boolean Value = (String xx).contains("3");   if (!Value){ error.append(" response is invalid");     Here I would like to set the parameter that String xx should have a value which cannot be greater than 3...

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `substring`

```
String s = "java";
String result = s.substring(2,s.length - 1);
```

You can figure out the logic of the exceptional cases which you want to handle seperately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = keyboard.next();
char startChar = str.charAt(0);
if(startChar !='a')
    System.out.println(str.substring(2));
else
   System.out.println("a"+str.substring(2));
```

Comment: Or just simply add `"a"` instead of `str.substring(0,1)`

Comment: `str.toCharArray()[0]` -> `str.toCharAt(0)`, to avoid copying the entire string into a char array for the sake of one character.

Comment: @Thanks gonzo! Your technique was a jem ;)